# How can I compile and generate libraries of boost version 1.82.0 in Aix?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, aix, xlc

Compiling the boost C++ library 1.82.0 on AIX 7.2 using xlclang++

I am trying to build the b2 binary using xlclang++ but getting std errors

```
class.cpp:
warning: unknown warning option '-WL' [-Wunknown-warning-option]
/usr/include/sys/inttypes.h:98:18: error: 'short wchar_t' is invalid
typedef unsigned short  wchar_t;                ^
/usr/include/sys/inttypes.h:98:1: warning: typedef requires a name [-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef unsigned short  wchar_t;
object.h:62:38: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
        inline explicit object(const std::string &val)`
                                     ^
```

Comment: Unlike C, `wchar_t` is a builtin type in C++, so there is no need to define it again in headers like `sys/inttypes.h`. `g++` for example comes with fixed include files, so you could try using it instead. Or you could add this flag to your CXXFLAGS: `-D_WCHAR_T`